# How to mount drive to a volume shadow copy by DefineDosDevice?

Tags: windows, powershell, device, drive, volume-shadow-service

I have created a volume shadow copy(eg \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy19) and I want to access the volume shadow copy by a device name(eg x:) in order to backup my system.
I have tried the DefineDosDevice:

```
DefineDosDevice(DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH, (LPCWSTR)"x:", (LPCWSTR)"\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy19")
```

It returns success but I can't enter x: in PowerShell(raise DriveNotFoundException):
[exception in powershell when I input 'x:'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWJ9w.png)

My system is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Comment: If the caller is running as or impersonating SYSTEM, its local device directory is the global "\DosDevices" in the object namespace (nowadays a link to "\GLOBAL??") . Otherwise the local device directory is "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logon ID>", based on the user's logon-session ID. Note that a standard/elevated token pair with UAC has a logon session for each token. You can get the process ID of the desktop session's shell via `GetShellWindow` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId`; open the process and impersonate its token; and call `DefineDosDeviceW` in the desktop session context.

Comment: Or to define the device globally, get the session server process ID from `CsrGetProcessId()`; enable SeDebugPrivilege and open the server process with limited-query access; open and impersonate its SYSTEM access token; and call `DefineDosDeviceW` in the global system context.

Comment: FYI, creating a link to a device in a logon session or global context is not "mounting" it. A device name such as "C:" is not a mountpoint. The primary volume mountpoint is a filesystem root directory mounted at the root path on the device, e.g. "C:\", "\\?\BootPartition\", "\\?\Volume{GUID}\". Additional volume mountpoints and bind mountpoints can be set on directories in file systems the support reparse points (NTFS, ReFS). A drive can also be set as a bind mountpoint to an arbitrary directory (subst drive), and UNC shares are bind mountpoints in the namespace of "\Device\Mup".

Comment: You should use `L"X:"` to create a wide string literal in C++.  Wide strings (`LPCWSTR`) are encoded differently from ordinary strings (`LPCSTR`); reinterpret-casting between them won't get you the expected results.